# Detecting jQuery off() in external javascript

Tags: javascript, events

Event's are not being fired after some external JavaScript runs. My event's are attached dynamically such as:

```
$("document").on("whole lot of of events", "#some.selector", doStuffFunction() {});
```

Based on checking:

```
getEventListeners(node);
```

I assume that event's are being removed from the element somewhere within external JavaScript (some calendar plugin), I have reason to believe it might be due to "off" function being invoked during the process.

Is there a way to detect when some specific function was called, so that I could possibly "override" the external function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that event's are being removed from the element somewhere within external JavaScript (some calendar plugin)...

If you've verified that it's really removing your handlers with a blind `$(document).off("the events")` or similar, **wow** would I stop using that calendar.

There's no built-in notification. It's easy enough to monkeypatch `off` though, and re-attach your handler:

```
var off = jQuery.fn.off;
jQuery.fn.off = function() {
    var result = off.apply(this, arguments);
    if (this === document) {
        // Re-attach your handlers
    }
    return result;
};
```

Or alternately, prevent the call to the real `off` entirely when it affects your handlers, but it's probably simpler just to reattach.

Obviously, you have to do that in code that runs prior to the calendar plugin's code.

Another option is to edit the code of the plugin to add a namespace to all its events, so the `off` call doesn't affect your handlers. (Perhaps even feed that back to the plugin author as a pull request.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of this, I understand it's not a good solution, but I guess there are some situations wheere there aren't any.